# Express: POST does not send data - var is not defined

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post

In a view, i am trying to get the data that a user sent, via a form, from another view.

This is the view with the form (i have omitted some EJS stuff to avoid confusion):

```
<form action="/renderer" method="POST" id="sc-form">
    <label for="model">Choose a model:</label>
    <select name="model" id="model">
        <% data.forEach(function(dat) { %>
           <option value="<%= dat %>"> <%= dat %> </option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Render the model!" />
</form>
```

As you can see, the user selects from a dropdown, and then data is POSTed on `/renderer`.

So, let's handle this POST request on `routes.js`:

```
app.post('/renderer', function(req, res) {
        var myModel = req.body.model; 
        res.render('renderer.ejs', {data: myModel});
});
```

Pretty basic, we get the data that the form sent and we send it to `renderer.ejs` as parameters.

Finally, let's grab the data on `/renderer.ejs` (this is inside a `<script>` tag):

```
var modelName = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
```

And i get this error:

```
data is not defined
```

But why is that? Data is the name of the variable that the router sent to the view, as parameter.

This is the third day that i am trying to make POST data appear on another view. If anyone could help i would really appreciate it.

Comment: did you try `console.log(myModel)` after reading it from req.body ?

Comment: @SélimAchour I just did. It doesn't show up. So the error must be in the form, or on routes.js?

Comment: It's all about "signal flow" (i'm a sound engineer) ... Start from the source (chrome ?) and see what is being sent in the Network tab of the developer console.
Does the request contain a proper body with the model variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this.
The form has to contain role="form", or else it wouldn't work.